# Any efficient way to render nested json list in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am able to fetch REST API where I can get nested `json` output, and I want them to display in React component. Now I only can render them in the console which is not my goal actually. I am wondering if there is an efficient way to do this for rendering nested `json` list in React. can anyone give me a possible idea to make this work?

**here is what I did**:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class JsonItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return <li>
      { this.props.name }
      { this.props.children }
    </li>
  }
}

export default class List extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
    data: []
    }
  };   
  componentDidMount() {
      fetch("/students")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
          this.setState({
          data: json
          });
      });
  }
  list(data) {
    const children = (items) => {
      if (items) {
        return <ul>{ this.list(items) }</ul>
      }
    }
    return data.map((node, index) => {
      return <JsonItem key={ node.id } name={ node.name }>
        { children(node.items) }
      </JsonItem>
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <ul>
      { this.list(this.props.data) }
    </ul>
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

**my current output**:

in my above component, I could render nested list on the console like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**desired output**:

how can I properly render out nested `json` output on React?  Any idea to make this happen? any thought? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you knew `.map()` is the common solution for this. But you can make this much better like below.

```
export default class List extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoaded: false,   //initally the loading state is false.
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      fetch("/students")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
          //updating the loading state and data. 
          this.setState({data: json, isLoaded:true}); 
      });
  }

  render() {
   //Waiting ajax response or ajax not yet triggered.  
   if(!this.state.isLoaded){
     return(<div>Loading...</div>);
     }else{
       //Rendering the data from state.
       let studenDetails = this.state.data.map((student, i) => {
         let uin = student.uin; 
         let studentInfo = Object.keys(student.studentInfo).map((label, i) => {
         return (
            <div key={i}>
              <span>
               <strong>{label}: </strong>{`${student.studentInfo[label]}`}
              </span>
            </div>
         );
        });
        return (
         <div key={i}>
           <h3>{uin}</h3>
           <p>{studentInfo}</p>
          </div>
        );
       });
      return (<div>{studenDetails}</div>);
     }
    }
   }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: can you share the fiddle? I just typed the code not yet complied.

Comment: give me a min. let me update the answer. @beyond_inifinity

Comment: if you are able to compile your solution with a fully working example on the fiddle that would be a big plus. Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer. @beyond_inifinity

Comment: How can I do collapse or expand student info for rendering? like accessing uin and studentinfo? Can you guide me? Thanks for your awesome solution.

Comment: Do you need only collapse/expand with sort by uin? or more. If you need more you can simply render that information inside `RectTable` it will take care of search, sorting and pagination. @beyond_inifinity

Comment: I want to access UIN and collapsing studentInfo, and also access UIN and expanding studentInfo, how can I make this happen? can you help me with that? could you extend your solution when you use `ReactTable`? thanks much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192249/discussion-between-prabu-samvel-and-beyond-inifinity).

Answer (score 0):

To render a list in react use the `.map()` function to build a list of `jsx` elements.

```
render() { 
  let myRenderedData = this.state.data.map((x, index) => {
    return <p key={index}>{x.uin}</p>
  })
  return (<div>{myRenderedData}</div>)
}
```

Comment: you're missing the key `key={x.someUniqueKey}`

Comment: @Gonzalo.- can you provide fully working example instead? thanks

Comment: @beyond_inifinity and no, you don't need to use the `JsonItem` component to render a list.

Comment: Well if you tell me what error you're getting I might be able to help you. There's nothing wrong with this answer, assuming `uin` exists as a property on your data set. If you want to display other fields do `x.studentInfo.firstName` and so on.

Comment: @beyond_inifinity okay, but what does the error message **say**? I cant do everything for you. Im not psychic. I updated answer to try to make it easier to understand.

Comment: I got an error like this: `TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function`, why? does the above solution works for you? any idea? Thanks

Comment: @beyond_inifinity well in your constructor if you are setting `this.state.data` to `[]`, that problem shouldnt occur. Also when you are fetching students, make sure the value of `json` is an array. You gotta learn how to debug.

Comment: yeah, I fixed. but currently I only get uin, how can I render student info also? the idea is when I either can see uin and studentinfo and see one of them in a hierarchy? any thought?